# How to make my <ol> list horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gamh26o/237/):

I am trying to make horizontal scroll on `<ol>` list

This is my code:

```css
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  width: 240px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
  <ol>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>

    <li class="card">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
      </a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

I added this, but i don't know what is wrong in my code.

```
overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the float left and replace with display inline-block;

```css
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.card {
    display: inline-block;
 width:240px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
      <ol>
       <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
 
         </ol>
 
 
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.scroll>ol{ display: flex; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`white-space:nowrap` only works on `inline` and `inline-block` elements.

```css
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.card {
  display:inline-block;
  width:240px;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
  <ol>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" /></a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" /></a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" /></a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" /></a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" /></a>
      <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is just change

```
overflow: auto;
```

to

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

and then set a width and height of your scroll. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnsbgat2/)